# QuantLib error with qlPiecewiseYieldCurveData() on qlPiecewiseYieldCurve() with ZeroYield and ForwardRate

Tags: programming, yield-curve, quantlib

I'm using **QuantLibXL** to build a discount curve, a zero yield curve and a forward curve of the EURIBOR rate (**QuantLibXL** is downloadable [**here**](http://quantlib.org/quantlibxl/index.html)).

I've built an object of class `PiecewiseYieldCurve` through the `qlPiecewiseYieldCurve()` function and the `TraitsID` argument is set to `ZeroRate`.

When I use the `qlPiecewiseYieldCurveData()` function to get the zero rates, the ObjectHandler returns me the following error message:

```
qlPiecewiseYieldCurveData - 1st iteration: failed at 1st alive instrument, maturity September 10th, 2013, reference date September 3rd, 2013: invalid value (-1) at index 0
```

Similar issue with the forward rates curve.

What should I amend in my `qlPiecewiseYieldCurve()` to make it work properly?

(Maybe this question is more suitable to Stack Overflow than Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange?).

Comment: It depends on the data you're using.  What are you passing to the `qlPiecewiseYieldCurve` function?

Comment: `ObjectId = 0` ; `NDays = 2` ; `Calendar = "Target"` ; `DayCounter = 0` (default) ; `Accuracy = 0` ; `TraitsID = "ZeroYield"` ; `InterpolatorID = "LogLinear"`. Everything else is equal to 0 or default. The main argument here is `RateHelpers`, that is an array built up via `qlRateHelperSelection()` and this function does not return me any error.

Comment: What are the quoted rates passed to the rate helpers?

Comment: Objects of class `qlDepositRateHelper` built by `qlDepositRateHelper2()` function; it's a curve made up by EONIA, EURIBOR from 1M to 6M and EUR swaps from 7M to 50Y. No error in that, according to the ObjectHandler. Every rate is a spot rate, not a forward one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I've done some digging in the code.
It's an issue with the LogLinear interpolation; while trying to find the correct rate for the 1-week node, the bootstrapper wanders unchecked into a region of negative rates and the logarithms blow up.  At this time, I'm afraid the workaround is just to use some other interpolation.  Or recompile the library and the addin disabling negative rates, but that's a lot more complex...

Would you mind reporting this as a bug on the QuantLib mailing list, or the bug tracker at http://sourceforge.net/p/quantlib/bugs/? (You might need a SourceForge login for the tracker.)

Comment: Actually, with `Linear` it works fine. Your explanation of the issue is perfect, thank you. Just a question before accepting your answer (it's the second time you help me with `QuantLib` related issues, thank you very much): considering I need to deal with `QuantLib` during the next months, do you suggest me to subscribe to its mailing list to ask about specific code's issues like this?

Comment: Yes, I'd subscribe.